# Switch between different mysql server versions on a mac

Tags: mysql, macos

How do I switch between different mysql server versions on a mac. I had mysql 5.5 installed, and recently installed 5.6 as well. Now, I need to switch between these versions. However, I am unable to do so.

Comment: http://marc.vos.net/howto/mysqlmulti/

Comment: @FredericClose s suggestion is a good one, btw, I would recommend against having two versions of MySQL on the same computer, library conflicts is almost "a sure thing"

Comment: @nrathaus what are the potential problems, that you know of or have encountered.

Comment: The main issues I saw when I tried it under Ubuntu is that a few libraries overlapped/collided, causing unexpected crashes and hangs

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it and its very easy

Install the app linked at : https://dbngin.com/

I have used it and its really great

To access mysql in local terminal is

1. Click on mysql icon and select : Export environment Variables to Terminal

mysql --socket /tmp/mysql_3306.sock -uroot

While connecting yo Dbeaver its also same

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).